# Create new variables from row for each existing variable in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which look like:

```py
0  target_year ID   v1  v2  
1  2000         1  0.3   1
2  2000         2  1.2   4
...
10 2001         1    3   2
11 2001         2    2   2
```

An I would like the following output:

```py
0   ID   v1_1  v2_1  v1_2  v2_2  
1    1    0.3     1     3     2 
2    2    1.2     4     2     2
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), using the [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) of `ID` as columns.

Then we can use a list comprehension with `f-strings` to merge the `MultiIndex` header into a sinlge level:

```
cols = df.groupby('ID').ID.cumcount() + 1
df_piv = (pd.pivot_table(data = df.drop('target_year', axis=1)[['v1','v2']],
                         index = df.ID, 
                         columns = cols)
df_piv.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in df_piv.columns]


     v1_1  v1_2  v2_1  v2_2
ID                        
1    0.3   3.0     1     2
2    1.2   2.0     4     2
```

Comment: Good answer, to make it more as expected output, you maybe should do `cols = df.groupby('ID').ID.cumcount() + 1`

Comment: Yess thnks for suggesting @erfan

Comment: Seems fine, thanks ! Just need to modify it a bit for my true dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter column, reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last flatten in list comprehension and `f-string`s:

```
g = df.groupby('ID').ID.cumcount() + 1

df = df.drop('target_year', axis=1).set_index(['ID', g]).unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  v1_1  v1_2  v2_1  v2_2
0   1   0.3   3.0     1     2
1   2   1.2   2.0     4     2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data come in only two years, you can also `merge`:

```
cols = ['ID','v1', 'v2']
df[df.target_year.eq(2000)][cols].merge(df[df.target_year.eq(2001)][cols],
                                 on='ID',
                                 suffixes=['_1','_2'])
```

Output

```
    ID  v1_1    v2_1    v1_2    v2_2
0   1   0.3     1       3.0     2
1   2   1.2     4       2.0     2
```